# Is it necessary to prescribe in the smart contract to set the price and pass the NFT to another person?

Tags: solidity, python, openzeppelin, brownie

I am developing a smart contract to publish the NFT.
Since I am using ipfs to store json I made a function to create a collection that gets the metadata reference and mints the token.
Is it necessary to prescribe in the smart contract to set the price and pass the NFT to another person?

Comment: What do you mean by necessary?

Comment: @PatrickCollins I'm talking about creating a function in a smart contract something like setPrice() and passing

Comment: @PatrickCollins Or is it enough to call _safeMint() and _setTokenTURI() to put the nft up for sale ?